# Ironic phrase like Russian’s “no, didn’t hear”

Tags: translation, conversation, dialogue

Here’s a bit of dialogue which I literally translated from Russian:

> ― You should get a girlfriend!
>
> ― Girlfriend? Didn’t hear. . . .

The idea of the answer is to self-ironically point out not only that the guy doesn’t have a girlfriend, but also that he hasn’t even heard of their existence.

In Russian, it is a kind of idiom. What is the right way to express a similar idea in English?

Comment: "Irony: (MW3UDE) 1 a : feigned ignorance designed to confound or provoke an antagonist : DISSIMULATION". // Some ironic responses if said with a straight face: "'Girlfriend'? Never heard the word. (What's it mean?)" or "'Girlfriend'? Can girls really be friends?" or  "'Girlfriend'? What's a girl?" or "'Girlfriend'? I can always mute & toggle my PC to 'hibernate' or 'sleep' mode. What about a girlfriend?"

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this pretty new and already deadbeat meme is actually direct translation of corresponding English "never heard of it".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another idiomatic option (at least in British English) would be:

> You should get yourself a girlfriend.
>
> Sorry, never heard of it.

The use of the impersonal pronoun "it" is part of the humour; it indicates that the speaker not only has no girlfriend, but doesn't even understand the concept that a "girlfriend" might be a type of human being.

Answer (score 14):

A corresponding conversation in English might go something like this:

> ― *You should get yourself a girlfriend!*
>
> ― *A girlfriend? **What’s that?!***

It’s more sarcasm than irony, and the reply is often “[deadpanned](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/deadpan)”.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to turn the sarcasm back on the person giving obvious advice, you could say something like

> A girlfriend? I didn't get the memo.

or

> A girlfriend? I must have missed a meeting!

or

> A girlfriend? Gee, why didn't I think of that?

Any of these implies that the advice is so obvious that the person giving it is either stupid or callous (or both) for bringing up a topic that is already causing you significant discomfort.